# Storing an Array of values in a single checkbox?

Tags: html

Is it possible to store multiple values in a single checkbox?

For instance:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="[0,2]">
<input type="checkbox" value="[3,6]">
<input type="checkbox" value="[7,10]">
```

...

Comment: You can write it that way but then the value will of type string not array

Answer (score 0):

Without any example code to go off of, I have no idea what your endstate needs to be. Here is an example that will update an array every time you check or uncheck a box, and log the resulting array to the console. N.B...

- this uses jQuery to listen for the changes
- each array is broken down into its component elements and then stored in a flat array, as opposed to being stored as an array of arrays
- there is no sorting of the array elements
- elements are stored as text and not numbers

Depending on what you need, this may or may not matter to you.

```js
var arr = [];
$('#check input').change(function() {
  var temp = (this.value).split(",");
  if (arr.indexOf(temp[0]) == -1) {
 arr.push(temp[0],temp[1]);
  } else {
 var pos = arr.indexOf(temp[0]);
 arr.splice(pos, 2);
  }
  console.log(arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="check">
<input type="checkbox" value="0,2">[0,2]<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="3,6">[3,6]<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="7,10">[7,10]
</div>
```